# Should I continue to cook Chicken which has only started to cook briefly then cooled by mistake

Tags: food-safety, chicken, slow-cooking

I started to cook chicken casserole in the slow cooker, for about 20 minutes on high so that I could then turn it down to low and leave cooking. However, I accidently turned the slow cooker off and so the chicken has been left to cool and had been sitting there for 5 hours.  Can I now continue to cook this casserole in the oven?

Comment: The questions aren't really duplicates, but all of these (and others) answer your question: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2642/what-do-i-need-to-know-about-temperature-and-food-safety http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3472/is-there-a-problem-with-defrosting-meat-on-the-counter http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12992/why-is-it-dangerous-to-eat-meat-which-has-been-left-out-and-then-cooked

Answer (score 4):

Chicken which is essentially still raw should not be left out for 5 hours at room temperature. I doubt it's safe to eat anymore.

Answer (score 0):

That's a shame... Toss it in the trash.